# Save html form data to a txt file using php

Tags: php, html, web-hosting, forms

I am new to PHP and struggling,I have an HTML form kind of login form,I want to store that input values from html form to a txt file,These all files are hosted on free hosting site(i made it for learning purpose).I have tried lots of threads to achieve that but none of them worked for me till now.So can anyone please help me,I have tried as in code.whihc is not working

AN HTMl form,a php code file and a txt file,Three of them are hosted on a free web hosting 000webhost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<BODY>

<form action = "post.php" method="POST">
    <h1> Please enter your information to create a new login account</h1>
    <p>
        <label>Login Name:</label><input type = "text"  name = "name" />
        <label>Password:</label><input type = "password" name = "pwd" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </p>
    <input type = "submit" name="submit_btn" id = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    <input type = "reset"  id = "reset" value = "reset"/>
</form>
</BODY>
</html>
```

php file

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
 {
  $username = $_POST['name'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  $text = $username . "," . $password . "\n";
  $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a+');

    if(fwrite($fp, $text))  {
        echo 'saved';

    }
fclose ($fp);    
}
?>
```

I have uploaded data.txt already.

Comment: can you see in my question?there's a form contains login form?and a php script to get those values added by user and save it to a txt file?clear?

Comment: You're using `$_POST`, but your form is sending via `GET`.

Comment: @JonStirling - hello,I have changed my code,can you please help me in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a permission issue. Check write permission with `is_writable` or enable error output with `ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Change permissions for data.txt accordingly.