# How to export input html data to txt by php (problem)

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, input

i found this code on internet and i want to have these inputs:
name
check box with 5 items

this code saves user's info that selected in checkbox and his name in a text file

can someone help me to fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$Name = "Username:".$_POST['username']."
";
$Pass = "Password:".$_POST['password']."
";

$file=fopen("saved.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, $Name);
fwrite($file, $Pass,);
echo fwrite($file,"*************************",);
fclose($file);
}
?>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check').click(function() {
        $('.check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
</script>
<BODY>

<form action = "post.php" method="POST">

    <p>
        <label>Login Name:</label><input type = "text"  name = "name" /><br>

<input type="checkbox" type = "password"  name="pwd[]" class="check" value="male"> Male
<input type="checkbox" type = "password"  name="pwd[]" class="check" value="female"> Female
<input type="checkbox" type = "password"  name="pwd[]" class="check" value="other"> Other

        <br/>
        <br/>
    </p>
    <input type = "submit" name="submit_btn" id = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    <input type = "reset"  id = "reset" value = "reset"/>
</form>
</BODY>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post array contains item with the name of your input fields .
This will work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$Name = "Username:".$_POST['name']."
";
$Pass = "Password:".$_POST['pwd']."
";

$file=fopen("saved.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, $Name);
fwrite($file, $Pass,);
echo fwrite($file,"*************************",);
fclose($file);
}
?>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check').click(function() {
        $('.check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
</script>
<BODY>

<form action = "post.php" method="POST">

    <p>
        <label>Login Name:</label><input type = "text"  name = "name" /><br>

<input type="checkbox" type = "password"  name="pwd" class="check" value="male"> Male
<input type="checkbox" type = "password"  name="pwd" class="check" value="female"> Female
<input type="checkbox" type = "password"  name="pwd" class="check" value="other"> Other

        <br/>
        <br/>
    </p>
    <input type = "submit" name="submit" id = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    <input type = "reset"  id = "reset" value = "reset"/>
</form>
</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: may you fix this code please? i dont know anything about php and i need this code

Comment: This code works except that your php code should be in a file called post.php

Comment: i did this but it still doesnt work! i downt know how to call chackbox items into php part

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to understand how the form works.

You ask for Post-Data of `$_POST["username"]` and `$_POST["password"]`.
Those "Names" are defined by the "name"-Attribute of the corresponding Input. So to get a username you will have to have an Input like `<input type="text" name="username" />`.

Look now at your own HTML: You have defined an Input for the users name, but it has the Attribute `name="name"`. This will result in the Post-Data being stored in `$_POST["name"]`.

Also you only have one input, but ask for two values (username AND password).

As for your checkboxes I don't understand the reason their names are `name="pwd[]"`, but you should probably change them too. You also specify two types but that second `type="password"` is not recognized.

Edit: I checked again and decided to completely rework your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $Name = "Username:".$_POST['username'];
        $gender = "Gender:".$_POST['gender'];
    
        $file=fopen("saved.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, $Name);
        fwrite($file, $Pass);
        fwrite($file,"*************************");
        fclose($file);
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.check').click(function() {
            $('.check').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <form action = "post.php" method="POST">
        <p>
            <label>Login Name:</label><input type = "text"  name = "username" />
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" class="check" value="male"> Male
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" class="check" value="female"> Female
            <input type="checkbox" name="gender" class="check" value="other"> Other
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </p>
    <input type = "submit" name="submit_btn" id = "submit" value = "submit"/>
    <input type = "reset"  id = "reset" value = "reset"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I recommend you to [learn more about HTML forms](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Comment: this link is orginal code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144704/save-html-form-data-to-a-txt-file-using-php   i wanted to change password part with checkbox

Comment: Now I understand what you where trying to achieve. Better you put this kind of info in the question next time as we need to understand what you are trying to do. edited the code again so it should work

Comment: i wanted to have a form with this type: NAME / 3 check box / the users wirthe their name and select a check box and SUBMIT . then the information of this input save as a text file!

Comment: That is what the code I supplied should do. If you are getting any errors please comment them.